# Error: Could not find or load main class Test in command prompt

Tags: java, class, program-entry-point

I used Edit plus to write the code:

```
import java.lang.System;
import java.lang.String;
class Test 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

After compiling it in command prompt with javac and executing with java commnds,
I am getting "Error: Could not find or load main class Test".

It was working fine in eclipse.

I even created path and classpath. But didn't work.

```
C:\Users\sss>cd C:\Users\sss\Desktop\Siri Study\java prog\ratanJprog

C:\Users\sss\Desktop\Siri Study\java prog\ratanJprog>javac Test.java

C:\Users\sss\Desktop\Siri Study\java prog\ratanJprog>java Test
Error: Could not find or load main class Test
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your folder structures under _ratanJprog_? I think by default Eclipse will create a _src_ and _bin_ for you to place the source and compiled class repectively.

Comment: Slight observation, it's not necessary to import classes from the java.lang package.

Comment: Works for me. Try specifying the claasspath as current directory: `java -cp . Test`.

Comment: And what did you set for CLASSPATH environment variable? You mentioned that you created a classpath for that.

Comment: Thank you, Robert. Your answer worked for me.

Comment: Alex, I was using edit plus and not eclipse.

Comment: Morgan, thank you for pointing that out. I learned that java.lang is a default package and need not import it in today's class:)

Comment: @Alex, regarding classpath, I used   set classpath ="C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_152\lib\rt.jar";  . But I guess I used it wrong.

Comment: @Rathna In fact, you don't need to set any classpath environment variable, otherwise it will go to the wrong place to find class files. By default, it will use the current path, i.e. `.`, as the classpath, but environment will override it.

Answer (score 0):

Where you have written your code, go to that folder and type cmd in search bar [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oBih.png) and execute your pgm from there. I had faced same problem but that was solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

you should change the class modifier to public